# If linear map is identiy map on subspace and its factor space, then its determinant is one.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, linear-transformations

If $T : V \to V$ is a linear map and $H \le V$ a subspace, such that $T_H = \operatorname{id}_H$, i.e $T(v) = v$ for all $v \in H$ and also that $T$ induces the identiy transformation on $V / H$, i.e. $\overline{T}(v + H) = v + H$ or equivalently $Tv - v \in H$ for all $v \in V$.

Then do we have $\det T = 1$?

Comment: Mhh, $V \cong H \oplus V/H$ and $T$ being the identity on both would mean that $T$ itself is the identity; but there are maps fulfilling the assumptions which are not the identity like $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$ so where is my fault? Could you please clarify. Also what is the connection with the determinant?

Comment: I've posted a full answer. ($T$ is not an identity since we have $V\simeq H\oplus V/H$, not $V=H\oplus V/H$.)

Comment: Ok. But if I have two vector spaces $U, V$ and linear maps $T, S$ on them which are both the identity, then the combined map $R$ on $U \oplus V$ with $R(u + v) := T(u) + S(v) = u + v$ is also the identity. So am I right that by this isomorphism it follows we have a base of $V$ above such that $T$ has the identity matrix as representation matrix? (this confuses me right now, as the identity matrix is only similar to itself, so I might have some misconception in my mind right now...)

Comment: Ok, I see it. The map built from $T_{H}$ and the induced map $\overline T$, which gives the identity, is not equal to $T$. And in general we could not decompose maps in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e_1,\dots,e_k$ is a basis of $H$ and $\hat f_{k+1},\dots,\hat f_n$ a basis of $V/H$, then $e_1,\dots,e_k,f_{k+1},\dots,f_n$ is a basis of $V$. From $T(\hat f_j)=\hat f_j$ it follows $T(f_j)-f_j\in H$, so we can write $T(f_j)=f_j+$ a linear combination of $e_1,\dots,e_k$. Thus the matrix of $T$ in this base has the form $\left(\begin{matrix}I_k&0\\*&I_{n-k}\end{matrix}\right)$ and therefore $\det T=1$

Comment: You write the coefficients of the $i$-th basis vector in the $i$-th row of the matrix right? (this is different then in my references, where it is always the $i$-th column, so I am just asking to confirm).

Comment: Yes, I've written them on rows.